# MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ after deleting and recovering files

Tags: node.js, npm

I am a beginner, so my question may seem a bit stupid.

I have this problem when trying to run `npm start`:

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! planephd@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --progress --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the planephd@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I think it happened because I accidentally deleted these files from my computer when deleting cache stuff. Then I used `git recover` for all deleted files. But seems like they are still missing. Could you please help and explain why it's happening, thank you!

Comment: try to execute `npm i` befor starting the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to run `npm install`?

usually, the `node_modules` folder isn't tracked by git (this would be accomplished by a .gitignore file on your main folder) so I would think git wouldn't have the info to restore it.

By doing `npm install` you are going to check in your `node_modules` folder to make sure that all your dependencies are installed and have the correct version (if there is no folder, it will create it, if there is one, it will update it). npm will take the information from a file named `package.json` which is like the npm recipe to get the project up and running, sort of :)

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to mention that the first thing I tried was `npm install` because I had a similar problem before and it helped, but now an error repeated

Comment: did you modify your package.json file in any way? Did it come back with the git recover?